# Ruby: how to interpolate in a string?

Tags: ruby

Is a simple question about how to print an interpolation on a string in ruby
My method is this:

```
def hello(parameter)
  puts "hello + #{parameter}"
end
```

puts hello(name)
but irb, show me these message:
NameError: undefined local variable or method `name' for main:Object

It is about my commands to irb? or what i'm doing wrong in my code, 'cause i know that i 've a mistake but can't find where.

Thank you, it's my first post ejje.

Comment: What does this have to do with Ruby on Rails? Why are you using three different versions of Ruby on Rails in a piece of code that is only three lines long? Voting to close as unclear.

Comment: It was my first post, think that more labels, the question would be answered faster.
''ll keep practicing to post better next further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue lies in your call to `hello(name)`. `name` in this case is treated at the name of a variable, which you have not defined. If you meant for the console to print "hello + name", then you should call the function with the string "name", surrounded by quote marks: `hello("name")`.

Comment: Thanks for the help!!